# Adding to integers in a list which is inside a dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary which houses some integer values in a list:

```
d = {"Numbers": [5, 10, 15, 20]}
```

How do I access the integers within the list and add to them all at once? So if I wanted to add 10 on, it would look like this:

```
d = {"Numbers": [15, 20, 25, 30]}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `dict['Numbers']` will give you the list, but please change your variable name from `dict` to something else, `dict` is a built in name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
d['Numbers'] = [i+10 for i in d["Numbers"]]
```

Slightly more verbose:

```
new = [i+10 for i in d['Numbers']]
d.update({"Numbers": new})
```

Answer (score 1):

If the dictionary contains or will contain multiple keys, you can use dictionary comprehension and then list comprehension:

```
d = {"Numbers": [5, 10, 15, 20]}
new_d = {a:[i+10 for i in b] for a, b in d.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
d = {"Numbers": [5, 10, 15, 20]}
add = 10 # Amount you want to increase.
```

You can make a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
d['Numbers'] = [v + add for v in d['Numbers']]
```

That is the same as:

```
tmp_list = []
for v in d['Numbers']:
    tmp_list.append(v + add)
d['Numbers'] = tmp_list
```

But in one line.

And if you want to increase all the items of every keys in the dictionary:

```
d = {k:[n + add for n in v] for k, v in d.items()}
```

That was a dictionary comprehension and it's equal to:

```
tmp_dict = {}
for k,v in d.items():
    tmp_dict[k] = []
    for n in v:
        tmp_dict[k].append(n + add)
d = tmp_dict
```

Answer (score 0):

**Everyone will give you same old approach using loop :**

what about without loop :)

```
d = {"Numbers": [5, 10, 15, 20]}



list(map(lambda x:list((map(lambda y:x.__setitem__(x.index(y),y+10),x))),d.values()))
print(d)
```

output:

```
{'Numbers': [25, 30, 15, 20]}
```